# SVN: difference between current version and version where it was branched?

Tags: svn, branch, diff

I have a branch that was branched from trunk.
How do I get difference of the latest version on the branch against the version on trunk from which this branch was branched (using command-line)?

Answer (score 2):

Find revision number for branch:

```
$ svn log -r 1:HEAD --limit 1 --stop-on-copy
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r11698 | user | 2016-03-20 22:13:30 +0600 (вс, 20 мар 2016) | 3 lines
...
```

Use this number to find the difference:

```
$ svn diff -r 11698:HEAD
```